# UnsubscriptionErrorImpl On using switchMap which calls a service

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

As the title says i am using RXJS and in it i call a service and it returns

```
UnsubscriptionErrorImpl {message: "1 errors occurred during unsubscription:\n1) TypeEr…not read properties of undefined (reading 'type')", name: 'UnsubscriptionError', errors: Array(1)}
```

My code in `effect.ts`

```
loadUserProfile$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(ActionTypes.LoadUserProfile),
      take(1),
      switchMap (_ => this.userProfileService.getUserProfile().pipe(take(1), tap(res => console.log(res))) )));
```

My code in `userProfileService`

```
  public getUserProfile(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.accountBaseUrl + '/admin/users/me');
  }
```

My code seems right but i am still getting unsubscription error.

Answer (score 0):

modify you code as bellow:

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

loadUserProfile$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(ActionTypes.LoadUserProfile),
    switchMap(_ =>
      this.userProfileService.getUserProfile().pipe(
        map(res => ({ type: ActionTypes.LoadUserProfileSuccess, payload: res })),
        catchError(error => of({ type: ActionTypes.LoadUserProfileFailure, payload: error }))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

you can use the catchError operator to catche and handle any errors that occur inside the inner observable